# How to use react Hook state variables without a callback function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When my checkbox gets checked or unchecked specific data needs to be set.  Right now I am setting the value of checked as true or false in a state variable.  The problem is it does not have a callback function like setState does so when I update it in the onChange function it does not update in time for the next set of data to get updated properly. Setting the properties on newEnhanceableData depends on if the checkbox is checked or unchecked.  How do I update my checked property in time for the next line of newEnhanceableData to have it's properties updated?

Here are the state variables:

```
const [checkbox, setCheckbox] = useState({checked: true});
const [enhanceableData, setEnhanceableData] = useState({
  name: 'Item Clicked',
  properties: {
    ...defaultProps,
    activityLocation: 'Member - RAQ Contact Details',
    autopopulated: true,
    changeType: 'Add'
  }
});
```

And here are is where I update them:

```
<input 
  id='raq-sms-text-checkbox' 
  type='checkbox' 
  defaultChecked={true}
  style={{marginRight: 5}}
  onChange={() => {
    setCheckbox({checked: !checkbox.checked});

    const newEnhanceableData = enhanceableData;
    newEnhanceableData.properties.changeType = checkbox.checked ? 'Add' : 'Remove';
    newEnhanceableData.properties.autopopulated = false;
    setEnhanceableData(newEnhanceableData)

    console.log('checkbox: ', checkbox)
    console.log('enhanceableData: ', enhanceableData)

    sendEnhancedTrackEvent(enhanceableData);
  }} />
```

As you can see here the checked property gets updated after enhanceableData is already set:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need hooks at all and simply check the checked state inside your onChange function:

```
<label>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    onChange={ev => {
      const { checked } = ev.currentTarget;
      console.log(checked) // toggles to true and false
      // continue with the rest
    }}
  />
  Click me
</label>
```

If you'd like to move the logic somewhere else, useEffect might be useful:

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
   // do-enhanced-computing-stuff-here
}, [checkbox]) // <-- effect only runs if checkbox boolean state changes 

<input checked={checked} onChange={ev => setChecked(ev.currentTarget.checked)} />
```

Comment: The simple things :)